# element UI table get filtered data or indices of original data

Tags: user-interface, filter, element

I would like to access the filtered data of an `Element UI` `Table`.
https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table

Suppose the full `data` of the table looks like this:
`$index: {value}`

```
[
0: {A},
1: {B},
2: {C},
3: {D}
]
```

Now suppose I set a filter via `filter-method` on a column and the filtered dataset only leaves behind values B and D.
The table now looks like this:

```
[
0: {B},
1: {D}
]
```

whereas I would like to have the original indecies, or access the leftover data that the table shows.

```
[
1: {B},
3: {D}   
]
```

How can I do this, does anyone have an idea?
I basically want to color my cells via cell-class-name but because of this behahiour, the cells are not colored correctly while the data is filtered. If I could access the remaining data OR the original indecies that would solve my problem.
Thank you!

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
</head>
<div id="app">
<template>
  <div>
    <el-table
        :data="data"
        style="width: 100%;"
        height="600"
    >
    <el-table-column
            label="Index"
            width="60">
          <template v-slot="scope">
            <div class="data">
              {{ scope.$index }}
            </div>
          </template>
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column
            label="Data"
            :filters="[{text: 'A', value: 'A'}, {text: 'B', value:'B'}, {text: 'C', value: 'C'}, {text: 'D', value:'D'}]"
            :filter-method="filterHandler"
            width="100">
          <template v-slot="scope">
            <div class="data">
              {{ scope.row.value }}
            </div>
          </template>
        </el-table-column>
      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
  </div>
</template>
</div>
<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app', //Tells Vue to render in HTML element with id "app"
  data() {
    return {
      data: [{value: "A"},{value: "B"},{value: "C"},{value: "D"}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterHandler(value, row, column) {
      return row.value === value;
    }
  }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed property for your data, like

```
computed: {    
    filteredData() {
        return data.filter(....)
    }    
}
```